# Extracting XMPMetadata with Tika

Tags: java, metadata, apache-tika, xmp

I'm using Tika to extract Metadata from many types (images, video, etc...) using the AutoDetectParser. It works quite well and returns some metadata in a fully qualified naming style "`tiff:XResolution`" (xmp).

But if I compare a Metadata extraction from Tika and a rdf extraction from exiftool for instance, I can see that Tika doesn't return as many metadata.

Is there a programmatic way to retrieve every XMP metadata with Tika,
as exiftool does?

Edited : With AutoDetectParser, I get this:

> ```
> "date" : "2019-10-11T23:19:50Z",
> "X-Parsed-By" : "org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
> "created" : "2019-10-11T23:19:50Z",
> "ImageLength" : "540",
> "Last-Modified" : "2019-10-11T23:19:50Z",
> "Last-Save-Date" : "2019-10-11T23:19:50Z",
> "audioSampleRate" : "25",
> "save-date" : "2019-10-11T23:19:50Z",
> "duration" : "6.84",
> "ImageWidth" : "960",
> "creation-date" : "2019-10-11T23:19:50Z",
> "modified" : "2019-10-11T23:19:50Z",
> "Content-Type" : "video/mp4"
> ```

But, I need to get these tags:

```
XPAuthor
Artist
Copyright
Keywords
XPKeywords
```

When I test with exifTool, I get:

[image]

---

**Edit:** The version of Apache Tika I'm using is `v1.24`.